# Pandas_DataFrame_Connect_to_SQLServer:Issue on conversion resultset for Dataframe.values.tolist()

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, pandas, function

Requirement is to provide table names as below in Excel sheet data.xlsx

```
Snum  TableName TableTypeid TableType
1       TermA       1       load
2       TermB       1       load
3       TermC       1       load
4       TermD       2       temp
```

1. Read data into data frame from Excel
2. Filtered *TableType* as 1 and captured only load tables into data frame
3. Changed the data frame output to a list
4. Connected to SQL Server db
5. To iterate each item in the list -changed to string/removed brackets/removed single quotes/prepared sql query for each table/executed sql/counts moved to 0utput csv

Code is attached in image [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywYzC.png)

Problem here is :-

In the excel output I am only getting final table count which is *Term C* but I wanted the final result in csv as below for all the 3 load tables:

TableName SQL Query Count

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: Hi AMC, I have edited the initial post with more details and exact issue .Please check and help me in resolving the issue . Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).